# Direct Access in ubuntu subsystem

Tags: dns, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using the Direct Access function on Windows 10 to connect to my workplace. On windows, I can remote to one of our host named "wp-hostxxx" via ssh channel. 
However, on the ubuntu subsystem, I cannot ping any hostname, which only gives me a `Name or service not known` message. Seems like it cannot resolve our internal hostnames.  Any solution for this?

Comment: I'm guessing maybe you just need to hack /etc/hosts on your Ubuntu box :(  See if this link has anything helpful to you: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/416

Comment: @paulsm4 Thank you. Well, that's a nightmare since we have a lot of devices in IPv6 and sometimes their IP are dynamic :(